# Can't build solution because of missing NuGet references

Tags: c#, nuget

Like title says, I can not build my solution(C#) as NuGet is spitting out this error

> This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this
>   computer.   Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more
>   information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The
>   missing file is ..\packages\Fody.1.26.1\build\Fody.targets.

When I run Get-Package, it says no packages are installed.
How do I get rid of this(I have no need for the package anymore).

Thanks

Comment: Dereference these libs, delete the `.nuget` folder and all of the `packages.config` files.

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to use the project based nuget package restore!

Make sure you have the latest Nuget version (Tools -> Extensions and Updates)

When you go to build the project it should tell you it needs to download the nuget packages (or might just auto download them).

Edit not sure whats with the downvotes:

http://blog.davidebbo.com/2014/01/the-right-way-to-restore-nuget-packages.html

To find the menu item: "enable nuget package restore" right-click in the solution explorer on the solution - not on the project.

You get a message:

> Do you want to configure this solution to download and 
>       restore missing NuGet packages during build?

Answer (score 1):

Press Ctrl+Q then type "Package Manager Console", This will bring up a console like interface.

Type in

```
Uninstall-Package Fody
```

and press enter will remove this package for you