# Can not compile because of missing NuGet package

Tags: package, nuget

As the title says, I'm not able to compile a solution because of a missing package

I did some search but that didn't helped (unfortunally)

[How to download a Nuget package without nuget.exe or Visual Studio extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14894864/how-to-download-a-nuget-package-without-nuget-exe-or-visual-studio-extension)

[Can't build solution because of missing NuGet references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31698709/cant-build-solution-because-of-missing-nuget-references)

Part of the output from the console:

```
F:\Riot Games\tool\Poro-master\Poro\PoroLib\PoroLib.csproj(168,5): error : This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. 

Enable NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. 

The missing file is ..\packages\System.Data.SQLite.Core.1.0.94.0\build\net45\System.Data.SQLite.Core.targets.
```

I need help to download that specific package and the internet confuses me, I mean x Person tells me to go x and z Person tells me to go z

I.. dunno what to do..

Comment: You have to download the specific version.  Did you download this package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite.Core/1.0.94 ?  You can manually install it through the package manager console or follow the first link in your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22909506/this-project-references-nuget-packages-that-are-missing-on-this-computer)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check if your Visual Studio is configured to restore packages. From VS top menu: `Tools -> Nuget Package Manger -> Package Manger Settings` ensure that first two checkboxes are ticked:
[image: Nuget options]

If the above doesn't work check if a firewall is blocking VS access to internet. If not, download your package manually from [this link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite.Core/1.0.94) and add it your project locally:

1. From VS top menu: `Tools -> Nuget Package Manger -> Package Manger Settings`
2. Choose Package Sources from left
3. Add a new item.
4. Provide a name and a location ( the folder in which your downloaded package resides )
5. Don't forget to press `Update` button ( a bug in VS)
6. Right click on your project and `Manage NuGet Packages)
7. Choose your new source from top right
8. Click `Browse`. Your package is there.